# polymer 1.3 dom-repeat two arrays

Tags: polymer

I need a dom-repeat to loop over one array and for each item I also need an element of a second array in the same index location.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[my_array1]]"> 
  <div>[[item]]</div>
  <div>[[my_array2[index]]] </div> <!-- this does not work -->
</template>
```

How to solve?

Comment: Array bindings docs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a computed binding:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[my_array1]]"> 
  <div>[[item]]</div>
  <div>[[getElementFromArray(index, my_array2)]]</div>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    getElementFromArray: function(index, arr) {
      return arr[index];
    }
  })
</script>
```